# Objective C - Switching from WiFi to 3G and vice versa

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, reachability

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses the network. The iPhone communicate with my server via HTTP request and should work on WiFi and 3G.
I currently use `NSURLConnection initWithRequest` to send async requests to my server and get responses (but I will soon move to work with `ASIHTTPRequest` library)

One thing that I'm not sure about is,
**What happens when user device goes from WiFi to 3G (or vice versa)?**

I know that the same connection can't be used and new connection must be established.
But do I need to do something to handle this situation, or does `NSURLConnection` handle it automatically?
For example if I sent a request and in the middle of getting the response the connection changes, what will happen with this request?

I saw Apple's Reachability example code, and I know I can use Reachability to detect network changes, but not sure how to handle those changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the connection changes from 3G to WiFi, the current request will result in a failure status, and yes you will need to do something to re establish the connection (restart, resume, etc...)

Having said that, i am not sure, but i think `ASIHTTPRequest` has a mechanism to fix these issues when you for example request to download a file